# Problems with autowired and timertask

Tags: java, spring, annotations, timertask

I'm having some problems with annotations and the timertask class. I'm trying to add the autowired bean into the schedule, but I get the error: NullPointerException. Why? I'm quite new to Spring and would be happy if someone could give me a hint. Please ask if I can provide you with more info.

```
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
public class TimeIntervalTriggerService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeIntervalTriggerService.class);
    private static final int updateFrequency = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3;

    @Autowired
    UpdateTableTask updateTableTask;


    public TimeIntervalTriggerService() {
        super();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateTableTask,5000,updateFrequency);
    }
```

Here is the TimerTask class

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UpdateTableTask  extends TimerTask{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdateTableTask.class);

    @Autowired
    TimerProcessor timerProcessor;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOG.info("Is working??");
        timerProcessor.doIt();
        LOG.info("It is working!!");

    }
}
```

The error:

```
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timeIntervalTriggerService' defined in file [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/fremad/WEB-INF/classes/fremad/service/TimeIntervalTriggerService.class]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [fremad.service.TimeIntervalTriggerService]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [fremad.service.TimeIntervalTriggerService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="fremad"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: According to Spring exception you have NullPointerException in TimeIntervalTriggerService constructor.

Comment: Well, yes. Maybe I should have stated that in the question.

Comment: And you have issue in this code, you cannot autowire bean with request scope into bean with singleton scope this way, in this way you just will have both singleton beans.

Comment: I thought that I could use the scopedProxyMode for that. Do you have any suggestions how to accomplish the same without the singleton? I want this bean to always live?

Comment: Ahh, sorry my bad, yeah , you are right scopes are correct :)

Comment: Tip `context:component-scan` already implies `context:annotation-config`. Saves you a line of xml (and another if you remove the comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proces the `@Autowired` annotations a bean instance is required. The dependencies are set AFTER the execution of the constructor. In your constructor the dependencies are still `null`.

Instead of your constructor move the logic to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateTableTask,5000,updateFrequency);
}
```

However instead of doing this stuff yourself why not simply use Spring to schedule the bean for you...

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="timerProcessor" method="doIt" fixed-delay="5000" initial-delay="1000"/>     
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Saves you some code. Or simply slap a `@Scheduled` annotation on the `TimerProcessor.doIt` method and use `<task:annotation-driven />` instead.

See the scheduling section of the reference guide.